# Display new layout after spinner click

Tags: android

Is it possible to open completely new layout after clicking on filter spinner ? Because in getDropDownView standard method I can only add textView , and what I need to do is put another spinner inside that first one - I hope I make myslef clear :) It's like a filter inside filter :) I tried to use onClick method but it doesn't work on spinner.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.new_layout)` should work in an Activity, but that will completely replace the layout, so maybe you don't want to do that.

Comment: but where should I put this ? OnClick doesn't work

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you should be using `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: That's cool but I don't really want to open dropdownview :) I mean - I've got spinner in my app (just like textView, but with the first position from list on it)  - I want to click on them and bang - new layout should show, but not standard adapter's dropdownVIew :)

Comment: Could you please show some code or maybe a picture about what you mean? A `Spinner` will make a dropdown. I don't know if you can just replace the dropdown layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the 2nd `spinner` as invisible. Set its visibility to `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` (based upon your need) initially. Then once the 1st `spinner` is selected, you should set the `setOnItemSelectedListener` and in the `onItemSelected()` method you can mark the 2nd spinner as visible by setting its visibility to `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what is meant by "completely new layout"

Comment: @cricket_007 I think OP is just confused. Have you seen any UI in which after selecting the spinner, the user goes to a new activity, or the entire screen changes? I suggested this suggestion, because he mentioned filter. _Generally_ how the filters work is you select something (from spinner) and then based upon that selection, some other options show up. Anyways lets wait for OP to respond and see what he actually needs.

Comment: I have seen strange things... but nothing like that, no :) I could understand a Spinner changing a Fragment within an Activity, but not blow away the full screen. As far as using two spinners go, I would just replace the adapter on the existing spinner.

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand your points. And as per your suggestion, of replacing the adapter on the existing spinner, again not what I had in mind. Consider this, you have a spinner for country. You select a country, and the next filter is for state. So in that case, once you select the country and we use your approach, then the countries would be replaced by states and you wont be able to choose the country again. Again, there can be infinite scenarios. We can just suggest OP, it all depends upon him what his requirements are :)

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions :) Ok, let's stay with countries example :) I've got main spinner with countries - let's click on it - they've got status(another spinner) : democratic, communist and stuff like that - my imagination ;) , population : 20 mln , >20 mln and so on - this is another spinner so we've got two extra spinners inside "country spinner" :)

Comment: Ok, one more thing, do all the countries have the same set of options? Like US would have status and population spinner, would UK have the same spinners too?

Comment: If its the same, then my suggestion above would work. You can put your other 2 spinners (population and status) in a layout, and hide that layout. Then `onItemSelected()` of your country, you can make the layout visible.